# Controlling two traction motors in a car

Tags: inverter, brushless-dc-motor

I'm doing an ev conversion and decided to go with two PMSM motors and two inverters (each for one axis). I'm trying to understand how to control the power output on each axis. I know that RPMs on both axis need to be the same (otherwise the wheels would slip), so torque is the parameter that will be divided between these two motors.

Do I need to buy specific inverter models that support such arrangement or is it possible to control the power output on each axis with some microcontroller?

Comment: please ask a specific question that has more detail ... `is it possible to control the power output on each axis with some microcontroller?` is answerable with `yes` ... it is unclear if you are asking for a confirmation

Comment: rpms will be different while cornering

Comment: I thinnk you mean "each axle", rather than "each axis".

Comment: I believe that each motor requires an individual inverter and the driver should command equal torque from each motor torque by use of the "accelerator" pedal. There may need to be some limit set on the speed differential between the two wheels to avoid wheel-spin. That limit would reduce the torque command to whichever wheel exceeds the limit. A microcontroller could probably be programmed to handle the wheel-spin prevention. The inverter needs to have the capability for PMSM torque control.

Comment: How do existing EV companies do it? Obviously you've researched this, right?

Comment: How is the full drive train setup? A diagram would help. Depending on the layout of the EV the needed behavior of the Motors changes.